# Permutations Alphabet

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

how many ways are there to arrange 10 letters taken from the alphabet a-z such that:

a) a is not included

b) z is included

c) both a and z are included

I believe for the first one it should be 25!/15!, but would both b and c be 
26!/16!?

Comment: b) $\frac{25!*10}{16!}$


c) $\frac{24!*9*10}{17!}$ ?

Comment: Ok is this correct now?

Comment: c) $\frac{24!*9*10}{16!}$

Comment: Yes @mathnoob that's correct, without any doubt

Comment: For b) first I get all permutations of $9$ letters not including $z$, then I have to insert $z$ into the permutations, there are $10$ places to put $z$, hence multiply by $10$. For c) the reasoning is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For second case it should be $25\choose 9$$×10!$
In this case , I have chosen $9$ letters out of $25$ since $Z$ is already included. After that I arranged the letters

For third case it should be $24\choose 8$$×10!$. 
In this case , I have chosen $8$ letters out of $24$ since $Z$ and $A$ are already included. After that I arranged the letters

Note: $n\choose r$ stands for combination.

Comment: I have been using the permutations formula p(n,r) = n!/(n-r)! So I am not quite sure why one would use combinations? I thought this was a permutation question because the order matters.

Comment: Oh , I think the better way would be to select first and then arrange, in this way you can get a clear picture of what is happening.

Comment: For b) first you choose $9$ letters out of $25$ because you already choose $z$. Then you permute $10$ letters so you multiply by $10!$. For c) first you choose $8$ letters out of $24$ because you already choose $a$ and $z$, then you permute $10$ letters.

Comment: I might. If I were to use permutation formula directly, for part B it would be 25!/15!? Since n = 25 and the denominator is (n-r)!?

Comment: Yeah man that's the logic.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see now

Comment: So could c(25,9) be converted to 25!/(25-9)!9! using the combinations formula? @AkashRoy

Comment: ®Akash you shouldn't ask for upvote, they will do on their own , if they like ur answer

Comment: Yeah Cloud JR I think he has understood now.

Comment: Ok @Cloud JR , greedy of reputation 

Comment: consider adding mathnoob comment to your answer

Comment: Should I elaborate my answer?

Comment: I upvoted without you asked, and people will do it , just give quality answer

Comment: How would you convert part b to the way @mathnoob has laid out part c?

Comment: The logic behind your answer makes sense @AkashRoy

Comment: Yes, elaborate it a little , it will help other to understand

Comment: Please check the elaborated answer and let me know if more is to be added.

Comment: Could b) be equivalent to (25!*10)/16!

Comment: Yes man of course.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: Anytime @charlie